# How do I find circular symbolic links?

Tags: unix, find

I'm working on a HP-UX system and I want to find if there are any circular symbolic links.

So far I'm using the command:

```
ls -lrt  `find ./ -follow -type l`
```

But it's only doing `ls -lrt` on current directory as result.

What command should I use to find all circular symbolic links in a system?

Comment: `ls -lrt`? *long* format, sort by *time modified*, *reversed*? Did you mean to tag linux? Because on a Mac, these options don't make sense.

Comment: @Daniel: The options are identical in GNU Coreutils. Also, the post explicitly mentions HP-UX, not Linux or OS X.

Comment: I didn't tag mac anywhere :). I tagged unix.

Comment: @grawity Huh. OK. I thought they maybe did something interesting on a GNU/Linux machine. Switching between Mac/Linux systems is generally a pain because of the command line arguments, so I just had to ask.

Comment: @user Mac OS X is a certified Unix system based on BSD. While you didn't specifically tag `osx`, I didn't *completely* ask without a reason. There is btw no `-follow` argument to `find` in Unix — I assume that's GNU only.

Comment: should this question be a serverfault.com question?

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -lrt  `find / -follow -type l`
```

./ searches the current directory.  If it happens to be / then your command as you wrote it will search from the root directory.  Otherwise lose the leading dot.

Comment: `find / -follow -type l -exec ls -lrt {} \;`?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this answer helps: [How do I find circular symbolic links?](https://serverfault.com/questions/265598/how-do-i-find-circular-symbolic-links/265614#265614)

Comment: It's the same question...

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
find -exec sh -c 'readlink -f "$0" &> /dev/null || echo "$0"' {} \;
```

Comment: HPUX does not have readlink except as a system call in C.  Unless the system has added gnu utils depots